# Function hoisting in javascript from condition statement

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Why

```
 var y = 1;
  if (function f(){}) {
    y += typeof f;
  }
  console.log(y); // 1undefined
```

Before running code I suppose it will be `1function`

I suppose that behind function hoisting f should be visible for all code. Can you provide link for such behavior description?

P.S> at blog post where I find this example there is explanation

> The output would be 1undefined. The if condition statement evaluates using eval, so eval(function f(){}) returns function f(){} (which is true). Therefore, inside the if statement, executing typeof f returns undefined because the if statement code executes at run time, and the statement inside the if condition is evaluated during run time.

But it doesn't make situation clearer

Comment: what is the question? and also what is the purpose?

Comment: I suppose it will be `1function`

Comment: I know but why are you trying to do this? can you give a real world example? I'm just curious

Comment: Write this: `var f = function(){};` before the if, and you'll get `1function`.

Comment: That's a function expression, not a declaration, and therefore not introducing any variables in any scope. And the quoted explanation is rubbish, there is no `eval`

Comment: @LUH3417 I don't understand your answer. Berge describe what i miss ( about expression, not declaration )

Comment: Basically I said the same: `f` is visible only within its function scope, not in any parent scope. So in the parent scope `f` isn't assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion here is that the syntax `function fName() {}` is ambiguous and depends on context.

Alone, it is a function declaration and is therefore hoisted. But in certain contexts it is a (named) function expression and therefore isn't.

This is why you see IIFEs declared as `(function() {..})()` or `!function() {..}()` to force them into being function expressions rather than declarations.

The important thing about named function expressions is that their name is essentially local to the function itself, and is not accessible outside that function. This is why `+= f` appends `undefined` in your code.

Of course, this is all completely pointless. Why would anyone in their right minds write such code? So I would like to leave you with this: https://youtu.be/RAA1xgTTw9w :)